# Get unique rows when datetime exists on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

Hello I have a table where I insert every time that I count a piece. Using an order, at the same day could be more than one order. In that table I'm inserting the current shift. What I want to do is to get the first row of every shift and doesn't matter if in that shift are more than 1 order.

At the moment this is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Part [Model], Station , Operators, Workorder, ShiftId, 
min([Date]) [StartDate], CONVERT(date, min([Date])) [StartDateFormat] 
FROM  Orders
WHERE Station IN ('S1', 'S2')
group by Part, Station, Operators, Workorder, ShiftId
order by Station
```

For the complete example please [check this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e6f04/6)

What I expect as my result is the following table:

```
Model  |  Station  | Operator  |  Workorder  |  ShiftId  |  StartDate            |  StartDateFormat  |
A1     |   S1      |   5       |  45010001   |     1     | 2020-01-17T10:24:08Z  |   2020-01-17      |   
A1     |   S1      |   5       |  45010022   |     2     | 2020-01-17T11:35:08Z  |   2020-01-17      |
A1     |   S1      |   15      |  45010004   |     3     | 2020-01-18T19:35:08Z  |   2020-01-18      |
Rows for Station S2 Are OK
```

In other words, I want to get the first row from every shift

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: *I want to get the first row from every shift* - first row from every shift **per day**?

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко Exactly! The first row from every shift per day. No matter if there are 20 rows for station 1, for shift 1 for yesterday, I want the first row. And same with all days.

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко I'm trying to solve it using **ROW_NUMBER**, but I'm not very familiarized with this function

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this top 1 per group problem.

One solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.date = (
    select min(o1.date) 
    from orders o1
    where o1.shiftId = o.shiftId and cast(o1.date as date) = cast(o.date as date) 
)
order by o.date
```

This gives you the earliest record per day and shift.

If you want the first record per shift over all days, you can slightly modify the query:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.date = (
    select min(o1.date) 
    from orders o1
    where o1.shiftId = o.shiftId 
)
order by o.date
```

I also like the anti-`left join` technique:

```
select o.*
from orders o
left join orders o1 
    on  o1.shiftId = o.shiftId 
    and cast(o1.date as date) = cast(o.date as date)
where o1.id is null
order by o.date
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you need something like that:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  PART [MODEL],
                    STATION,
                    OPERATORS,
                    WORKORDER,
                    SHIFTID, 
                    [DATE]  AS  [STARTDATE],
                    CONVERT(DATE, [DATE]) AS [STARTDATEFORMAT],
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, [DATE]), SHIFTID ORDER BY [DATE])  AS  RN
            FROM    ORDERS
            WHERE STATION IN ('S1', 'S2')
        ) V1
WHERE   V1.RN = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e6f04/15)